# How to cross-fadeing image in Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-animation, tumblr, android-progressbar

Basically, I have images that I'd like to to update them sequentially into the same view to create custom `ProgressBar`.

I found Tumblr to do just that with their ProgressBar(ImageView?).

Here I put the animation side-by-side to show how the image actually cross-fade from Aa into a camera.
[image: Tumblr progress view]

Exactly what I wanted:

> 1. Cross-fading effect
> 2. Indeterminate
> 3. Use the same view (I dumped view hierarchy to check)
> 4. Animation during transition (The image actually pop a little when spinning and cross-fading into the next image)

So far I have tried:
1. [Frame Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Frame),
 this allows for unlimited item(s) with definable durtion. However, it
 doesn't cross-fade the image and there's no way to listen to the
 transition's event to apply other animation, etc.
 2. [Transition Drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Transition), this allows cross-fading between EXACTLY two drawables. So this doesn't allow for the number of items and interminate duration as well.

I also came across [CrossFadeDrawable](https://code.google.com/p/shelves/source/browse/trunk/Shelves/src/org/curiouscreature/android/shelves/drawable/CrossFadeDrawable.java?r=15) by Romain Guy just now but it looks like it's only coded to support only two Drawable.

Right now I am not very sure if I'm approaching in the right direction or is there something I need to learn in order to do this kid of effect?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are approaching this direction but isn't this what you are looking for:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=atH3o2uh_94

Comment: Yes, I have. That's Transition Drawable. As I stated in my finding #2, it only support cross-fading between two drawables.

Comment: And because you looked at TransitionDrawable you probably also noticed that it holds a simple list of Drawables via mLayerState.mChildren and hardcoded indices. So though there seems to be no framework support you got everything to code it yourself.

Comment: I went looking inside TransitionDrawable, a lot of classes they are using were protected subclass inside `android.graphics.drawable`. To imitate the whole process will require moving classes and styles from Android to my own application.